# Checking if vector<unsigned char> contains string

Tags: c++, vector, binaryfiles

I am trying to read many binary fils(exe, or dll) and checking if they contain the string. problems begin, when I try to implement simple way to check that, but that is always being quite ubiquitous. Checking for every char with if is possible, but it is just sooo loong... Considering that my string is 30+ chars long.

Code so far:

```
string path = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\dllDir";
    int i = 0;
    for (const auto& file : filesystem::directory_iterator(path))
    {
        ifstream ifs(file.path().c_str(),ios::binary);
        vector<unsigned char> buffer(istreambuf_iterator(ifs), {});
        system("pause"); // Debugging :)
    }
```

Is there easy way to check presence of string in binary vector file without 30+ if statements? :)

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "string" in contrast to "sequence of characters" (which you are guaranteed to get from a file). I ask because I feel that you might have skipped the implicit special meaning of "string" you are using.

Comment: "is just soooooo long"  is insufficient information for helping you improve your approach. Please show it as a [mre].

Comment: Are you sure that there's no [standarard algorithm function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) so ***search*** for sequences in containers?

Comment: And if you need to implement this yourself, then you just need to find the *first* byte. If found, then check the next byte, etc., until you either have a full match or there's a mismatch. If there's a mismatch continue searching for the first byte from the last found position.